# Can I apply functools.wraps to a normal function, which is not a decorator or a decorator factory?

Tags: python, type-hinting, functools

I have a function like this

```py
def load_resources(path: Path, src_type: str, *, load_all: bool = False) -> bool:
    ... # something happens here and return a value
```

Then IDE(which is VScode in this case) gives me useful information when using `load_resources` including this kind of type hint.

```
(function) def load_resources(path: Path, src_type: str, *, load_all: bool = False) -> bool
```

Calling the function takes some time so I wanted to put `functools.lru_cache` on the function. (I am using python3.8)

```py
@functools.lru_cache()
def load_resources(path: Path, src_type: str, *, load_all: bool = False) -> bool:
    ...
```

Then `lru_cache` shades the information of `load_resources`.

```
(function) load_resources: _lru_cache_wrapper[Unknown]
```

So I tried `functools.wraps` like this.

```py
def __load_resources(path: Path, src_type: str, *, load_all: bool = False) -> bool:
    ...

@functools.wraps(__load_resources)
@functools.lru_cache()
def load_resources(*args, **kwargs):
    return __load_resources(*args, **kwargs)
```

but it gives me a weird type hint like this.

```
(function) load_resources: _Wrapped[(__load_resources(path: Path, src_type: str, *, load_all: bool = False), bool, (*args: Hashable, **kwargs: Hashable), Unknown]
```

I knew that `__name__` of the function went wrong but I thought other features will be applied properly.

Is it just wrong using `functools.wraps` out of the context of decorators? Then how can I attach type hints to the functions decorated by `functools.lru_cache`?

---

I just did like this.

```
def load_resources(path: Path, src_type: str, *, load_all: bool = False) -> bool:
    return __get_context(path, src_type, load_all=load_all)
```